# Custom image generator with inputted text and image to implement on wordpress website

Tags: jquery, wordpress, image

I am trying to build my wordpress website and I want to achieve this type of automation as in this site: https://www.tagsforhope.com/product/personalized-pet-id-tags/  where the user can input the text they want, upload the image they want and a card gets generated based on those specifications. Right now, for my clients I use photoshop but I want a way to be able to automate it if the design template is ready.

Viewing the source code has shown that it is implemented in JQuery.
Any suggestions for tutorials or anything which might be a good starting point for me to practice?

Comment: Well this a big scenario, We simply can't help you over here. First of all you need to design the for. On click of button, open the popup, in side the popup you have to give option to upload a image. And after that ofcourse it needs Jquery Ajax call.

Comment: @Samir - Thank you for trying to help though :) Maybe I can search and work something out with the structure which you provided.